# Looping through database-images and centering them using CSS

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli

I am trying to create one row of three centered images inside a div. The images and the div will be centered on the page. The images will be inside the div, here's my code so far:

HTML/PHP

```
<?php
        $resultSet = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");

        if ($resultSet->num_rows != 0)
        {
             while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $id = $rows["id"];
                $image = $rows["image"];

                if ($id <= 3)
                {
                    echo "<div id=main>";
                    echo "<img src=$image>";
                    echo "</div>";


                }
            }
        }
```

CSS:

```
body{
    position: relative;
}

#main{
    background-color: red;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline;

}

#main img{

    width: 10%;
}
```

I've tried text-align: center, margin: 0 auto, position: absolute (left/right: 50%) on the #main div, sometimes it centers, but it makes the images as blocks (right on top of each other), instead of inline. How do I center the div and images on the page, with the images being right next to each other?

Comment: Take a look at this recently asked question earlier today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326996/centering-two-images-horizontally-aligned-in-a-single-div

Comment: @Matt This does align everything to the center, but the images are stacked on top of each other, instead of aligned horizontally together.

Comment: Wrap <center></center> around your divs

Answer (score 0):

Try this styles for #main..

```
    <style>

body{
    position: relative;
}

#main{
    background-color: red;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
}

#main img{

    width: 10%;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to iterate your images as cells in a table...

The below code will hold three images, evenly spaced out in a row; which is horizontally centred.

```css
.image-grid {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  max-width:60%;
  margin:0 auto; /*Horizontal centre*/
}
.image-grid .item {
  display:table-cell;
  width:33.333%; /*Three along*/
  height:200px;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class='image-grid'>
  <div class='item' style='background-image:url(...)'></div>
  <div class='item' style='background-image:url(...)'></div>
  <div class='item' style='background-image:url(...)'></div>
</div>
```